# Android HTTP: get out of infinite while loop with sending requests to Apache server

Tags: python, android, apache, apache2

this is a schema of my project:

1) Android app -> 2) Apache server on RPi -> 3) Python scripts that control -> 4) my device

**1) Android app** - 2 simple switches, each one sends different request to Apache on RPi:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Switch switch_auto = findViewById(R.id.switch_auto);
    Switch switch_manual = findViewById(R.id.switch_manual);

    switch_auto.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                new Background_get().execute("led1=1");
            } else {
                new Background_get().execute("led1=0");
            }
        }
    });

    switch_manual.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCheckedChanged: SET TO TRUE");
                new Background_get().execute("led2=1");
                Log.d(TAG, "onCheckedChanged: EXIT");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCheckedChanged: SET TO FALSE");
                new Background_get().execute("led2=0");
                Log.d(TAG, "onCheckedChanged: EXIT");
            }
        }
    });

}

private class Background_get extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.248/?" + params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                result.append(inputLine).append("\n");

            in.close();
            connection.disconnect();
            return result.toString();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

**2) Apache server on RPi** - very simple PHP code:

- if it was "led1=1", launch Python script that makes device work for 10 seconds (`time.sleep(10)`)
- if it was "led1=0", just print something
- if it was "led2=1", launch another Python script that makes device work for an indefinite period of time (`while True: time.sleep(1)`)
- if it was "led2=0", launch third Python script that stops the device

**My problem**: I can correctly control my device with these scripts by web browser, for example:

- http://192.168.0.248/?led2=1 will turn the device on and make it work
- http://192.168.0.248/?led2=0 will turn the device off

For testing purposes, this is Apache2's access.log for **led1** (=1 makes it work for 10 seconds, =0 does nothing more than print a line):

> 192.168.0.10 - - [01/Mar/2018:**10:42:01** +0100] "GET /?**led1=1** HTTP/1.1" 200 411 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186
>   Safari/537.36"

*(It starts working)*

> 192.168.0.10 - - [01/Mar/2018:**10:42:05** +0100] "GET /?**led1=0** HTTP/1.1" 200 233 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186
>   Safari/537.36"

*(No problem to get led1=0 just after 4 seconds and led1=1's script still works for few more secs)*

**Unfortunately, I cannot do the same with my Android app**. Here's same Apache's logs:

> 192.168.0.66 - - [01/Mar/2018:**10:36:53** +0100] "GET /?**led1=1** HTTP/1.1" 200 411 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 8.1.0; Nexus 5X
>   Build/OPM3.171019.014)"

(*I make a "switch off" after 5 secs but...*)

> 192.168.0.66 - - [01/Mar/2018:**10:37:07** +0100] "GET /?**led1=0** HTTP/1.1" 200 232 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 8.1.0; Nexus 5X
>   Build/OPM3.171019.014)"

(*It didn't! Notice 14 secs of difference (it launches about 3 secs and then work for 10 secs). It receives GET after led1=1's script finished its work*).

This is a concern when script is working for 10 secs (led1) but a big problem when the script is working in infinite while loop (led2) - I cannot break it until first script stops (but it's while True loop so...)

I was thinking about Python's `subprocess.check_call()` in second script to kill the first one but it didn't seem to help.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: It is orear where you are talking about. It begins already with `if it was "led1=1", launch Python script that makes device work for 10 seconds (time.sleep(10))`. Device? I woud think switch a led on for ten seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to do it. The idea of killing infinite while loop was correct but firstly I was thinking about doing it on Python scripts which was wrong.

I noticed that those GET responses didn't appear in logs while local .php site was loading (due to while loop) so there was a need to abort current GET. And it can be done with Apache's httpcomponents.

So after some modifications my code looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
boolean flagToggle = true;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Switch switch_auto = findViewById(R.id.switch_auto);
    Switch switch_manual = findViewById(R.id.switch_manual);


    switch_auto.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        HttpGet requestOn = new HttpGet();
        HttpGet requestOff = new HttpGet();

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (!flagToggle) {
                requestOn = new HttpGet();
                requestOff = new HttpGet();
                flagToggle = true;
            }

            Background_get switchOn = new Background_get(requestOn);
            Background_get switchOff = new Background_get(requestOff);

            if (isChecked) {
                switchOn.execute("led1=1");
            }
            else {
                requestOn.abort();
                switchOff.execute("led1=0");
                flagToggle = false;
            }

        }
    });

    switch_manual.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        HttpGet requestOn = new HttpGet();
        HttpGet requestOff = new HttpGet();

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (!flagToggle) {
                requestOn = new HttpGet();
                requestOff = new HttpGet();
                flagToggle = true;
            }

            Background_get switchOn = new Background_get(requestOn);
            Background_get switchOff = new Background_get(requestOff);

            if (isChecked) {
                switchOn.execute("led2=1");
            }
            else {
                requestOn.abort();
                switchOff.execute("led2=0");
                flagToggle = false;
            }

        }
    });
}

public class Background_get extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private HttpGet mRequest = new HttpGet();

    public Background_get(HttpGet newRequest) {
        mRequest = newRequest;
    }

    public HttpGet getRequest() {
        return mRequest;
    }

    public void setRequest(HttpGet newRequest) {
        mRequest = newRequest;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URI url = new URI("http://192.168.0.248/?" + params[0]);
            // HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            getRequest().setURI(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(getRequest());

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                result.append(inputLine).append("\n");

            in.close();
            // response.close();
            // httpclient.close();

            return result.toString();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Things worth noting:

- for each toggle-switching it needs separate request (new HttpGet())
- same with BackgroundGet (because it's AsyncTask)
- flagToggle helps with multiple toggle-switching